# ellipse angles at foci formula

Tags: trigonometry, conic-sections

I read (in multiples sources) that for any point P on an ellipse $\frac{\tan\frac{\phi}{2}}{\tan\frac{\theta}{2}}=\frac{1-e}{1+e}$ where *e* is the eccentricity of the ellipse and $\theta$ and $\phi$ are as in the image below. How is this formula derived from plane trigonometric formulas? I tried using the [law of tangents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_tangents) or the [law of sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines) on the triangle $F_1F_2P$ together with the fact that $PF_2=\frac{a(1-e^2)}{1+e\cos\theta}$ but no luck.
[image: ellipse].

Comment: use $\tan{\frac{A}{2}} = \sqrt{\frac{(s-b)(s-c)}{s(s-a)}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start from
$$
PF_1=\frac{a(1-e^2)}{1-e\cos\phi},\quad PF_2=\frac{a(1-e^2)}{1+e\cos\theta}
$$
and use $PF_1+PF_2=2a$ to obtain
$$
\frac{1}{1-e\cos\phi}+\frac{1}{1+e\cos\theta}={2\over1-e^2}.
$$
Now substitute the identities:
$$
\cos\phi={1-\tan^2{\phi\over2}\over1+\tan^2{\phi\over2}},
\quad
\cos\theta={1-\tan^2{\theta\over2}\over1+\tan^2{\theta\over2}}
$$
and expand everything: you'll get your formula.